# Pause PyTest and wait for user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

How can I pause a running test and wait for user input?

I have an unconventional test (python 3, pytest) where I want to "pause" to ask the user (me) for a id code before continuing on with the test.

I'm aware this is not standard, and would like to know how to solve the problem.

Example Test:

```
    def test_oauth_flow(self):
        url_jwt = auth(id=client_id, scope=scope)
        id_code = webbrowser.open_new(url_jwt)
        # pause wait for user input.
        # use code to complete flow etc....
        auth = auth(code)
        assert auth is 1
```

Comment: It is probably a better idea to mock the input and have the test run automatically.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I'm running functional test against an external API. I have to get a code to continue.

Comment: I see... Can you mock or stub the API?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque unfortunately not. I need to run on their development system. I would have to build my own open id server to mock this otherwise.

Comment: This would make your tests dependent on a human, do you really want that? I would hate a test suite that requires me to sit and input something to proceed. Also, you can forget about automated runs on a CI server etc. Wouldn't it be better to automate acquiring this information you have to input? Surely you can write some code that will query the OpenID server for credentials that will be then passed in the test.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add stdin interaction with pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43575274/how-to-add-stdin-interaction-with-pytest)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it will always depend on what are you testing but my recommendation is to run ContractTests against the external API and record the responses to latter have this data available for your functional tests.

To record the responses you can use vcr, its a Ruby tool: https://github.com/vcr/vcr, but there is also a python implementation (I haven't used it) https://github.com/kevin1024/vcrpy

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/5053#issuecomment-484921801), it's possible but pytest's default capturing needs to be dialed back to `sys`:

```
$ pytest --capture=sys ./tests/
```

Then this test function will halt the tests with a user prompt:

```
def fd_input(prompt):
    with os.fdopen(os.dup(1), "w") as stdout:
        stdout.write("\n{}? ".format(prompt))

    with os.fdopen(os.dup(2), "r") as stdin:
        return stdin.readline()
```